# Issue with dijit.Dialog and remote content

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am trying to open a `dijit.Dialog` when the user clicks on a link.

Furthermore, I want for this **dialog to fetch the remote content of the iframe (e.g. the google home page) when the dialog opens** and not when the page containing the dialog loads.

Here is the JS:

```
dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");


function showDialog() {
    console.log('showDialog');
    dojo.byId('ifr').src = 'http://www.google.fr';
    dijit.byId('dialogOne').show();
}
var link = dojo.byId('link');
dojo.connect(link, 'onclick', showDialog);​
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="link">open link</a>

<div id="dialogOne" data-dojo-type="dijit.Dialog" title="My external dialog">
<iframe id='ifr' width='300px' height='450px'>         </iframe>
</div>​
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8eenG/6/

However, this doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally misread your question and went ahead and starting hacking away.

This doesn't load remote content, but it fixes all of your other problems.

See demo here:  http://jsfiddle.net/5uuCX/

**Javascript**

```
require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom", "dijit/registry"], 
function(parser, on, dom, registry) {
    parser.parse();
    on(dom.byId("link"), "click", function(e) {
        registry.byId('dialogOne').show();
    });
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="link">Click to Open Dialog</a>    
<div id="dialogOne" data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog" title="My external dialog">
    <div id="foo" data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/ContentPane" href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/259fD/show/">    
    </div>
</div>​
```